# Where is errindex set in netsnmp for a SNMP SET request that fails?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

When is the errindex supposed to be set to the appropriate value in the response PDU for an SNMP SET request that fails?
Thank you!

Comment: Your question is tagged with net-snmp, but the question is worded generically about the protocol and not about Net-SNMP's API.  which do you need help with?

Comment: net-snmp API. I am returning an error message from a handler function, but I an not sure how to set the error index... hence the result is (generr) instead of the actual particular error e.g. SNMP_ERR_BADVALUE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't set the error-index using the Net-SNMP API.  The problem is that your loop over the requests should actually always return SNMPERR_SUCCESS to indicate the handler succeeded even if some of the SNMP request components didn't.

To indicate a particular request failed with an error message, you would use the following API:

```
                    netsnmp_set_request_error(reqinfo, request,
                                              SNMP_NOSUCHOBJECT);
```

for example.  For picking the correct error to return, please see section 4.2.5 in [RFC3416](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3416/) which has a nice step-by-step procedure for returning the right error code for a given situation.

Comment: 10x! I really missed it... That was really useful indeed!